# How to run Bitbucket CI locally

Tags: android, bitbucket, android-espresso, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm currently trying to set up Bitbucket CI for my Android project, but in order to be able to run my Espresso tests on a connected device I need to run the scripts of bitbucket-pipelines.yml locally, as I do in other projects hosted on Gitlab.

I can't use a docker image, as RSA fingerprint changes in every run and I have to accept manually the alert that pops up on my device.

I wonder if there is any option to run the shell scripts in my computer or if there is some way to mantain RSA fingerprint persistent between runs.

I mustn't change my Git client.

Comment: What's your question? Your title is `How to run Bitbucket CI locally`. Your issue is that `RSA fingerprint changes`. You're asking `any option to run the shell scripts in my computer` and `if there is some way to mantain RSA fingerprint persistent between runs`. Why not have 1 concrete question?

Comment: My question is how can I run my Bitbucket CI locally, but I'm asking more concrete questions in the description in order to achieve that.

Comment: so you want people to give you three answers? What if someone gives you one good answer? Is that considered wrong?

Comment: Any answer that solves the main problem will be marked as correct. Asking this questions it's a way of giving some feedback to the question.